# ndgrid and interpn - matlab

Tags: matlab, interpolation, mesh, spline

I have 4 grids:

1. `kgrid` which is [77x1];
2. `x` which is [15x1];
3. `z` which is [9x1];
4. `s` which is [2x1];

Then I have a function V which is:

5. `V` [77x15x9x2]

I am trying to interpolate V at some `kprime` points. To do so, I am doing:

```
[ks, xs, zs, ss] = ndgrid(kgrid, x, z, s);
Vprime = interpn(xs, ks, zs, ss, V, xs, kprime, zs, ss, 'spline');
```

where `kprime` is a [77x15x9x2].

All the matrices needed (kgrid, x, z, s, V and kprime) can be found here: http://www.filedropper.com/grids

However I am getting this error when using

```
Error using griddedInterpolant
Data is not valid NDGRID format.
Error in interpn (line 149)
           F = griddedInterpolant(X{:}, V, method,extrap);
```

Any clue on what could be the issue?

Comment: Are `kgrid`, `x`, `z`, and `s` all monotonically increasing?

Comment: Yes, indeed. They are all monotonically increasing.

Comment: I think you need to conserve the ordering used in the output of `ndgrid`. `interpn(ks, xs, zs, ss, V, kprime, xs, zs, ss)`

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right! Silly me. Thank you, this was driving me nuts. If you want to post that as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of the inputs to `interpn` need to be the same order as the outputs of your `ndgrid` call. You have flipped `ks` and `xs`.

```
vprime = interpn(ks, xs, zs, ss, V, kprime, xs, zs, ss);
```